# JQuery unable to get the previous image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, image

i have this scenario:

```
<img class="prev" data-modal-img-src="asd"/>
<span></span>
<img class="next"/>
```

now on cllick i want to get the .prev img element src attr, and i do:

```
$(function(){
$('span').bind('click',function(){
 var _img_src = $(this).prev('img').attr('data-modal-img-src');
 alert(_img_src);
});
});
```

it doesn't works as expected, any suggestion?

P.S: do not use -1 like is rayining -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the prev they should have common parent could by `body` tag or `div` etc. and you do not have attribute `'data-modal-img-src'`. You should use `on` instead of bind as bind is *deprecated*. Also use `data()` instead of `attr()` for data attributes.

> **prev()**, Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector, [jQuery documents](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5YAfJ/2/)**

```
<img class="prev" data-modal-img-src = "123"/>
<span></span>
<img class="next"/>

$(function () {
    $('span').bind('click', function () {
        var _img_src = $(this).prev('img').data('modal-img-src');
        alert(_img_src);
    });
});
```

Using `data()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5YAfJ/1/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('span').bind('click', function () {
        var _img_src = $(this).prev('img').data('modal-img-src');
        alert(_img_src);
    });
});
```

Comment: well .. there is really no other way then setting a common parent? also without using prev() don't know ..

Comment: You can use class or id selector if you have single element and do not have repeated sequence.

Comment: yep but as you described i jsut need a parent, shouldn't <body>  be a common parent? anyway i got a parent

Comment: Yes body is their parent. I mean to have common parent to apply prev. I have already updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data()` rather than `attr()`

```
$(this).prev('img').data('modal-img-src')
```

Comment: `data('xxx')` is equivalent to `attr('data-xxx')`.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes of-course but preferred is data since the attribute is set as data format

Comment: Preferences should be put in a comment, since it's not the answer to the question.